# decompress multiples pdf files without using tmp files?

Tags: bash, backup, pdf, compression, tar

I have more than 100.000 pdf files
I want to decompress it, then recompress theme all in one archive file to save space.
all i found is:

```
ls | xargs -P 4 -n 1 -I {} qpdf --stream-data=uncompress {} /tmp/RAM/{}
```

then

```
tar -c /tmp/RAM | xz > archive.tar.xz
```

any solution please ?

Comment: Have you run tests whether the PDFs are indeed smaller, and whether they are still usable? In order to get the smallest possible PDF, you'd have to interpret and properly recreate the PDF, getting rid of all kind of junk in the document (the simplest example is doing a Save as… in Acrobat).

Answer (score 0):

In linux, you can use `tmpfs` which is a in-memory filesystem, but be careful as it might be too small for you to use:

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
tmpsfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
...
$ mkdir /dev/shm/tmp
```

You can expand its size, but be careful no to ask too much.

```
$ mount -o remount,size=1G /dev/shm
```

See [this post](https://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs) for more info